# replace only white spaces (no tabs, no line end) of a tabular file with underscores

Tags: string, replace, whitespace, tr

I need to replace only white spaces of a tab delimited file with underscores (but keeping the tabulation and the division in lines). The file is composed of 5 million lines and 8 columns, here the first two lines as example:

```
Contig505_strand1_frame2_coord21-810    sp|Q06605|GRZ1_RAT Granzyme-like protein 1 OS=Rattus norvegicus PE=2 SV=1   32.245  245 153 6   5.15e-33    123
Contig505_strand1_frame2_coord21-810    sp|P36178|CTRB2_LITVA Chymotrypsin BII OS=Litopenaeus vannamei PE=1 SV=1    34.483  232 140 7   1.78e-32    122
```

For now I am using these commands in sequence, but it's very slow...there is a quicker way to make it?

```
tr -s '\t' ';' <inputfile.txt >file2.txt
tr -s '[:blank:]' '_' <file2.txt >file3.txt
tr -s ';' '\t' <file3.txt >file4.txt
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[:blank:]` includes tabs, so I think if you want to replace one or spaces with an underscore this may work better:

```
sed -E 's/ +/_/g' inputfile.txt > file2.txt
```

The `sed` (stream edit) command searches for one or more spaces and replaces them with an underscore.  The 'g' is for global, meaning do the replacement multiple times on a line if found.  The default action is to replace only the first occurrence.